# XAML Converter ConvertBack

Tags: wpf, xaml, converters

Is there a way to access the ConvertBack-Method of a Converter that implements IValueConverter directly from XAML?

The basic situation is the following (relationsships):

`Route (1)<->(CN) Training (1)<->(CN) Kilometer`

The DataContext is set to a Training. From here I use the Convert-Method to access all my `Kilometers`. I also have a Converter from `Route` to `IList<Training>` and the ConvertBack would lookup the `Route` for a `Training`. But I seem to not be able to access that Method from XAML…

Comment: What does `CN` stand for? Could you please post your converter code?

Comment: CN = 0 to unlimited items exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually don't call the `Convert` or `ConvertBack` methods directly. They are only used in bindings. The `Convert` method is called to convert the source value before it is assigned to the binding target. The `ConvertBack` is called to convert the value back to the source in a two-way binding.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it doesn't seem like converters are your best option... perhaps you should give more details about what you want to achieve

Comment: I know that Converters are used in Bindings. Am I right, that there is no flag to manually instruct that ConvertBack should be used? If they can't be used, think it will be better to just write another Converter…

Comment: Yep. If you frequently have to do that, you might want to create an ReverseConverter that takes another converter as a property...